# Присвоение нескольких действий в переменную и использование ее в цикле

Tags: bash

Пытаюсь присвоить переменной Data несколько действий и использовать ее в цикле:

```
Data=$(tail -f -n 1 "$LOG2" | while read line; do grep "Start" | cut -d ' ' -f11; done)

if [[ $Data -ne 0 ]]; then echo "OK"; else echo "Error"; fi
```

Пока без успешно..
Как я понял проблема с экранированием, у меня с этим не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в чем была ошибка.
С tail флагом -f переменная просто не успевала обрабатыватся в цикле.